# scope not working in relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ruby-on-rails-3.1

My models:

```
class House
belongs_to: country
scope :published, -> { where(published: true) }
end

class Country
has_many: houses
end
```

I want to show the houses which are published and from country x;

```
house_controller:

@country = Country.friendly.find(params[:country_id])
@houses = @country.houses.published.order(:sorting)
```

I get the error "undefined method `published"

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: On the console, can you successfully do `House.published`?

Comment: And if `@country` is `nil`, I bet you'd be getting "undefined method 'published' for NilClass" or something like that, which would make total sense. Is `@country` nil?

Comment: your models are not looks good I can not see `ActiveRecord::Base` Please post it properly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can used published scope as the following:

```
House.where(country_id: @country.id).published.order(:sorting)
```